# how to create label button in PYQT?

Tags: python, pyqt

I need your help with my app. I undecorated python gui and now i need to create clicable label.

run.py

```
from PyQt4 import  QtCore, QtGui
import sys

import untitled

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, untitled.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()                              


def closeapp():
    sys.exit(0);
```

untitled.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 110, 85, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 58, 14))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 140, 58, 14))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "open", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "close", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "view", None))
```

Now I need to add action to label and label_2. How to make the label to perform closeapp()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a function to Ui_MainWindow class (untitled.py)

```
def click(self,eve):
    print "clicked"
```

Then add attribute to label object

```
self.label.mousePressEvent = self.click
```

another option is just modify run.py file like following

```
class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, untitled.Ui_MainWindow):
    def click(self,eve):
        print "clicked"
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label.mousePressEvent = self.click
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Comment: How to make so that the label was untitled.py, a click was run.py?

Answer (score 2):

`QLabel` inherits `QWidget`. [QWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html)` has an event handler [mousePressEvent](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)

so as E-ebola virus mentioned

add

`self.label.mousePressEvent = self.click`

and define

```
def click(self,event):
    #do something
```

or

subclass QLabel

```
class customLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
       QLabel.__init__(self)

    def self.mousePressEvent(self,event):
        self.emit(SIGNAL("closeapp"))
```

emit a `SIGNAL` when label is pressed, i would implement it as

```
self.label = customLabel()
self.connect(self.label,SIGNAL('closeapp'),self.close)
```

Comment: How to make so that the label was untitled.py, a click was run.py?

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to ask, can you be a bit clear

Comment: File untitled.py is generated by pyuic4 and every time this file is changing. I need to label button in a file run.py because this file is not changing :)

Comment: Initialise label in ExampleApp, as it is inheriting Ui_MainWindow you can change labels text or widget type in ExampleApp having its properties retained from auto generated code